# Sum where conditions - The multi-part identifier 't.column' could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this `SELECT DISTINCT` sql query and I'm trying to achieve that in column `TotalPaidPerEvent` would be SUM for `k.akce = q.akce AND z.kod - q.zpro`

I tried the `OUTER APPLY` but it seems that it is getting for each `z.kod` the same SUM. All I'm trying to achieve is that it would be unique count for `k.akce = q.akce AND z.kod = q.zpro`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    k.akce,
    z.firma,
    z.osoba,
    z.kod,
    qnt.TotalPaidPerEvent
FROM zprost z
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(q.zaplac) AS TotalPaidPerEvent
    FROM klient q
    WHERE z.kod = q.zpro
    ) qnt
LEFT JOIN klient k
    ON k.zpro = z.kod
WHERE rocnik = 2014;
```

When I try to do: 
Any help to achieve that?

```
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(q.zaplac) AS TotalPaidPerEvent FROM klient q WHERE z.kod=q.zpro AND k.akce = q.akce) qnt
```

I get following message:

`The multi-part identifier 'k.akce' could not be bound.`

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: can you add the complete query that displays that error and that table schemas?

Comment: Re. error: you need to join `k (i.e. klient)` prior to referencing it in the `outer apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need for `k` to be defined before it is used.  Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.akce, z.firma, z.osoba, z.kod, qnt.TotalPaidPerEvent
FROM zprost z LEFT JOIN
     klient k
     ON k.zpro = z.kod OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(q.zaplac) AS TotalPaidPerEvent
      FROM klient q
      WHERE z.kod = q.zpro and k.akce = q.akce
     ) qnt
WHERE rocnik = 2014;
```

However, I think the following might do the same thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.akce, z.firma, z.osoba, z.kod,
       sum(zaploc) over (partition by z.kod, k.akce) as TotalPaidPerEvent
FROM zprost z LEFT JOIN
     klient k
     ON k.zpro = z.kod
WHERE rocnik = 2014;
```

Comment: At the end I used the first sample, the second had some problem with `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` Thanks anyway, this helped me a lot.

Comment: @Marek . . . Try the second one again.  I had left code clutter at the end of the line.